# sql query to get info from the same table?

Tags: sql

lets say I have a table structure in the following format:

ParentItemId is an id to the Item table itself.

```
Item,  ItemId, ParentItemId
---------------------------
 Apple  1         0
Orange  2         1
Lemon   3         2
```

What i want is, given ItemId= 3, i want a list in the form of, (3,2) (2,1) and (1,0)

If given ItemID = 2, i want a list , (2,1) and (1,0)
ParentItemID = 0, is the terminating condition.

Is there an efficient way to do this in terms of a sql query? i could only think of doing this by joining the same table multiple times...

Comment: You have to join with same table again to get this output

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: im using sql server 2014..thnks